# Rank of Matrix equal over Q and R?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-rank

I am trying to prove a problem however I am stuck in the middle.
So the task is that for a given matrix $A$ with coefficients $a_{ij}$ element of Q, that the rank of this matrix over Q is the same its the rank over R.

My attempt: As there are more solutions in R, the kernel of A over R is larger, so $ker \, A_Q \leq ker \, A_R$ which yields $rank \, A_R \leq rank  \, A_Q$. However I can't see how to prove the other way $rank \, A_R \geq rank  \, A_Q$.

I have seen seen solutions with tensor products, however I am just asking for a hint with more elementary algebra.

Comment: You can find the rank by row reducing, and all of the row deducing operations only involve rationals if the matrix entries are rational.

Comment: That is what I thought too, however my instructor told me I should prove it this way.

Comment: @Magnetar what about using what Jonathan suggested, let say we have row reduced the matrix $A_Q$, we are left with 2 options, or we can not row reduced it over any bigger field or we can over $\mathbb{R}$, in this case we will get $Rank(A_Q)\leq Rank(A_R)$

Comment: Thanks gbox, that was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

A matrix $A$ having rank $n$ means that there is a non-zero [minor determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)) of order $n$, but none of a larger order (including the case where no larger order fits inside $A$).

Minors are just determinants of submatrices, and the result of calculating determinants (which are just sums and products of the entries of a matrix) is entirely independent on whether the rational entries in the matrix are interpreted as rational numbers or real numbers.

Comment: That is a point of view I didn't think about, thanks. However do you think it could be proven without determinants, but linear map theorems in general?